# deleting a set of elements from an array created using new in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to delete the last two elements from an array created using the pointer p as follows:

```
double *p = new double[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    cin>>*(p+i);
```

works fine till here, when I try to delete the last two elements in the array by offsetting the pointer p and then using delete in the following way

```
delete [] (p+3)
```

it will compile but then crashes.

Is this allowed, if yes then where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot delete individual positions from the originally allocated memory.

Comment: "Is this allowed?" No.

Comment: The rule is simple -- the **value** that is returned by `new / new[]` must be the same value you use for `delete / delete[]`.  Since you're giving `delete []` a value that was not allocated with `new []`, the behavior is undefined.  The value is whatever `new[]` assigned to `p` -- it is not `p+3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
double *p = new double[5];
```

there is allocated one extent of memory. You can not delete a part of it.

To solve the problem you need to allocate a new array copy elements of the old array into the new array and then delete the old array.

For example

```
double *q = new double[3];

std::copy( p, p + 3, q );

delete [] p;

p = q;
```

If the size of the array can be changed it is better to use standard container `std::vector<double>`.

For example

```
std::vector<double> v( 5 );

for ( std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
{
    std::cin >> v[i];
}

//...

v.erase( std::next( v.begin(), 3 ), v.end() );
```

Or

```
v.erase( std::prev( v.end(), 2 ), v.end() );
```